# opencv How to allocate completely new Mat using old Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to make completely new allocation of a Mat using old one.
The first solution works for me, but i prefer to find solution without saving the Mat:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "c:\\img.jpg"; 
imwrite( ss.str(),img_old);
Mat new_img = imread(ss.str());
```

The Second solution, which is not working for me:

```
Mat new_img = img_old.clone();
```

What is the difference between them?
How i perform this operation without saving the Mat?
I am looking for a solution similar to the second one.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: `Mat new_img = img_old.clone();` should work, but try `Mat new_img; img_old.copyTo(new_img)`;

Comment: the difference between `imwrite( ss.str(),img_old);
Mat new_img = imread(ss.str());` and `Mat new_img = img_old.clone();` is, that you lose image quality during saving to `jpg` file. And, if `img_old` is a grayscale image, `new_img` will be a color (CV_8UC3) image after loading from file. So either your following code might not work because your image hast too much noise (which might be removed after savin/loading jpeg), or your following code assumes e.g. a CV_8UC3 image but gets a CV_8UC1 image if you use `.clone()` (if your old image was CV_8UC1).

Comment: Thanks, img_old was grayscale image(CV_8UC1). So, this was the difference and the problem. In the first solution new_img was color image (CV_8UC3). In the second solution it was grayscale image(CV_8UC1).